# System.Text.Json JsonStringEnumConverter with custom fallback in case of deserialization failures

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have a .NET 6 program that needs to deserialize a JSON string value (returned by external API) into a .NET enum.

The issue is that there are over 100 possible enum values (and more could be added without my knowledge), but I'm only interested in a few of them. So I would like to define an enum type like this and deserialize all the values that I'm not interested in to `MyEnum.Unknown`:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3,
    // only values that I'm interested in will be defined
}
```

If I'm using Newtonsoft.Json, I can do this quite easily with a custom JSON converter:

```
public class DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    private readonly object _defaultValue;

    public DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter() : this(0)
    {
    }

    public DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter(object defaultValue)
    {
        _defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
        catch (JsonException)
        {
            return _defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

But with System.Text.Json, I can't figure out how this can be done easily, because the [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-6.0) in STJ is actually a `JsonConverterFactory` that doesn't do the serialization itself (it throws exceptions in all overrides of `JsonConverter` as you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a08d9ce2caf02455c0b825bcdc32974bdf769a80/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonConverterFactory.cs#L77-L107)). Instead the factory creates [`EnumConverter<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a08d9ce2caf02455c0b825bcdc32974bdf769a80/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/EnumConverter.cs)s that actually do the work, but `EnumConverter<T>` is internal so I can't even reference or inherit from it in user code.

Any idea how this can be done easily with STJ or is it not possible at all? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Could you just pull the enum into a string field and have a separate getter on your class that performs the mapping logic on read instead? That way you'd never lose the data that was returned from the external API as well.

Comment: @aegis Yes that's an option, and one that I would take if I can't find a suitable solution to deserialize it directly to enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and wrap the `JsonStringEnumConverter` factory in a decorator whose [`CreateConverter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterfactory.createconverter) method wraps the returned [`EnumConverter<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a08d9ce2caf02455c0b825bcdc32974bdf769a80/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/EnumConverter.cs) in some inner decorator that catches the exception and returns a default value.

The following does that:

```
public class DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter : JsonConverterFactoryDecorator
{
    public DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter(JsonStringEnumConverter inner) : base(inner) { }
    public DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter() : this(new JsonStringEnumConverter()) { }

    protected virtual T GetDefaultValue<T>() where T : struct, Enum => default(T);

    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var inner = base.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options);
        return (JsonConverter?)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumConverterDecorator<>).MakeGenericType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) ?? typeToConvert), new object? [] { this, inner });
    }

    sealed class EnumConverterDecorator<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : struct, Enum
    {
        readonly DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter parent;
        readonly JsonConverter<T> inner;
        public EnumConverterDecorator(DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter parent, JsonConverter inner) => 
            (this.parent, this.inner)= (parent ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(parent)), (inner as JsonConverter<T>) ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(inner)));

        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => inner.CanConvert(typeToConvert);
        
        public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            try
            {
                return inner.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, options);
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                return parent.GetDefaultValue<T>();
            }
        }
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => inner.Write(writer, value, options);
    }
}

public class JsonConverterFactoryDecorator : JsonConverterFactory
{
    readonly JsonConverterFactory inner;
    public JsonConverterFactoryDecorator(JsonConverterFactory inner) => this.inner = inner ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inner));
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => inner.CanConvert(typeToConvert);
    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => inner.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options);
}
```

Do note that, unlike Json.NET, System.Text.Json does not have an equivalent to Json.NET's [`ConverterParameters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute_ConverterParameters.htm) (see [issue #54187](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54187) for confirmation) so if you need a different default value for a specific enum, you will need to subclass `DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter` for that specific enum, e.g. like so:

```
public enum MyEnum2
{
    Unknown1 = 1,  // Use this value for unknown values
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3,
}

public class MyEnum2Converter : DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter
{
    protected override T GetDefaultValue<T>() => typeof(T) == typeof(MyEnum2) ? (T)(object)MyEnum2.Unknown1 : base.GetDefaultValue<T>();
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => base.CanConvert(typeToConvert) && typeToConvert == typeof(MyEnum2);
}
```

Then if your model looks like e.g.:

```
public record Model(MyEnum MyEnum, 
                    [property: JsonConverter(typeof(MyEnum2Converter))] MyEnum2? MyEnum2);
```

And your JSON looks like:

```
{"MyEnum" : "missing value", "MyEnum2" : "missing value" }
```

You will be able to deserialize and re-serialize as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new DefaultFallbackStringEnumConverter() },
};

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(json, options);

var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xlfahq).

Comment: Seems to be the most elegant way without requiring Microsoft to unseal anything. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom `JsonConverter`

```cs
public class MyEnumJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyEnum>
{
    public override MyEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
       return Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(reader.GetString(),true, out var val) ? val : default;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
       writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then add an attribute on the property you want the converter to kick in

```cs
public class Test
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyEnumJsonConverter))]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```